# how can I reduce time complexity from picking images from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, image

That is how I have my data:

```
(
   {
   image = "https://www.myurl/abc-  a/uploads/1161570652.jpg";
   }
   {
   image = "https://www.myurl/abc-   a/uploads/1161570652.jpg";
   }
   {
   image = "https://www.myurl/abc-   a/uploads/1161570652.jpg";
   }
   {
   image = "https://www.myurl/abc-   a/uploads/11615720652.jpg";
   }
   {
   image = "https://www.myurl/abc-  a/uploads/11615730652.jpg";
   }
)
```

I could retrieve it successfully. But the problem is it is very slow.

Here is my code:

```
seeview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

for (int k=0; k<[dictofimage count]; k++)
{
    img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:[image_array objectAtIndex:k]]]];
    NSLog(@"image name is 0 %@",img);
    [myimageview setImage:img];
}
```

It takes time to pick every element and is slow in progress. Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: This loop is pointless. The image view will only end up with the last image.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get away from looping through all of the contents of `image_array` so you're stuck with `O(n)` but you can use a faster construct. The `for:in` loop is much faster than a typical C style loop, so something like:

```
for (imageString in image_array) {
         img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:imageString]]];
       NSLog(@"image name is 0 %@",img);
       [myimageview setImage:img];
}
```

For a breakdown of the benchmarks check out: http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/high-performance-collection-looping-objective-c.html

EDIT: I should also note that `dataWithContentsOfURL` is a synchronous call that you probably shouldn't be making in this loop. You'd be better off creating an `NSOperation` that downloads the image, and when it finishes you can dispatch back to the main queue to set the actual image in the `imageView`.

Comment: dataWithContentsOfURL: actually goes out and fetches the image, that's probably why it's so slow. You should prefetch them, or do as Peter recommends and make it asynchronous

Comment: Ya, the crux of the performance issue is largely unrelated to the loop being used.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off handling the array of objects concurrently, in the background.  This is precisely what `dispatch_apply` is for.

```
dispatch_apply(
    image_array.count,
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
    ^(size_t index) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[image_array objectAtIndex:index]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Handle the image on the main thread for UI elements
        });
    });
```

You only need the `dispatch_async` if you need to handle the image on the main thread as part of a UI change.

Note, that `dispatch_apply` is synchronous, in that it kicks off one background task for each iteration.  Those tasks run in the background, but `dispatch_apply` will not return until they are all done.  Thus, you may also want to wrap that in an async block.

Or, you can do it yourself, and get notified when all the blocks are complete...

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
for (size_t i = 0; i < image_array.count; ++i) {
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[image_array objectAtIndex:index]];
        // The rest is the same...
    });
}
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    // This code will execute on `queue` when all the above blocks have finished
});
```

Note, however, that `dispatch_apply` has a nice algorithm to not overload the system.  The above approach is not so kind.

However, you can get `dispatch_apply` nice-ness using an async call.

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_apply(image_array.count, queue, ^(size_t index) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[image_array objectAtIndex:index]];
        // The rest is the same...
    });
    // This code will execute on `queue` when all the above blocks have finished
});
```